# Unable to load video stream in

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I am new to iOS development,

I want to stream video from webapi, The files are streamed from our backend server which requires authentication. It is key-based authenticated set in the Authorization HTTP Header.

I tried with AVPlayer didn't got my output. After doing some more research, i found customProtocol will be more useful do it so i have used customProtocol and tried with this code but the customProtocol is not getting called [customProtocol.h](http://pastebin.com/YFyuCaBV), [customProtocol.m](http://pastebin.com/KGX0qq7h)

```
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyCustomProtocol class]];

    NSString *theURLString = @"customProtocol://abcd.com/download";
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURLString]];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    [player play];
```

Can any one help me here? where i a making mistake?

**Thank you in advance!**

This is my customProtocol code :

```
@implementation MyCustomProtocol

+ (BOOL) canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSURL* theURL = request.URL;
    NSString* scheme = theURL.scheme;
    if([scheme isEqualToString:@"customProtocol"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

// You could modify the request here, but I'm doing my legwork in startLoading
+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

// I'm not doing any custom cache work
+ (BOOL) requestIsCacheEquivalent:(NSURLRequest *)a toRequest:(NSURLRequest *)b {
    return [super requestIsCacheEquivalent:a toRequest:b];
}

// This is where I inject my header
// I take the handled request, add a header, and turn it back into http
// Then I fire it off
- (void) startLoading {
    NSMutableURLRequest* mutableRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
    Constants *constants = [Constants sharedInstance];
    [mutableRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",constants.access_token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSURL* newUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:[mutableRequest.URL host] path:[mutableRequest.URL path]];
    [mutableRequest setURL:newUrl];

    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:mutableRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void) stopLoading {
    [self.connection cancel];
}

// Below are boilerplate delegate implementations
// They are responsible for letting our client (the MPMovePlayerController) what happened

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didFailWithError:error];
    self.connection = nil;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
    self.connection = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have passed authentication header with url then you can use below code

```
NSMutableDictionary * headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[headers setObject:@"Your UA" forKey:@"User-Agent"];
AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:URL options:@{@"AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey" : headers}];
AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
```

it may work...try it

Answer (score 1):

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController * movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

movieController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: hello  lalit thank u for ur kind reply but it still not working the player comes and dismisses quickly